# How can I test from the terminal whether my linux-based system can see a Windows domain name?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, samba

I have a backup service which stores the backup files in a share directory on a Windows server , but it fails and if I look in the logs I see this error:

```
13:02:13 AXSDBG notice tsrv-cmdqx(Backup->server)[30043] Result::_add(514) Connection to myfileserver failed (Error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME)

13:02:13 AXSDBG notice tsrv-cmdqx(Backup->server)[30043] Result::_add(514) Connection to myfileserver failed (Error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME), repeated 1 times
```

I googled it as saw this is a `SAMBA` error.

If I try to connect to **myfileserver** and path with the provided credential from a windows system it works.

How can I check why the services doesn't sees this name?

Comment: When you tried to connect to myfileserver yourself, did you do that with a different user than the one the service operates with? This could be a permission problem with the service user. better double check the permissions for that user and the directory that it accesses

Comment: @LumenAlbum I connected with the same user/password.